# can you separate inorganic ions with chromatography?

Tags: chromatography

For example,  if you run a solution of sodium and potassium chloride through a colum?
I am just wondering if i can get pure potassium chloride from a mixture of sodium and potassium chloride.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_chromatography may be helpful to you. I've never done this before so can't comment on how it would work in practice.